# Is the close on this question actually the answer?

Tags: discussion

This question was closed for being [opinion](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/63281/how-do-we-make-the-judgment-that-someone-is-a-herd-animal) based. I don't really mind, it's not a very diverting question. But I wondered whether that's an answer to the question: it's a matter of opinion how to tell if someone is a hard animal. Does that make sense?

Answer (score 2):

Read the first comment:

> Who are the "we"? Nietzsche? "Something eager to please, sickly, and mediocre... degenerating, infirm, who suffer necessarily". SE users?

If your question is "what do arbitrary self-selecting visitors to a website think?" then yes, the answer is "lots of arbitrary self-selecting opinions". Questions like that are useless, so we close them.

If someone wanted to ask what Nietzsche himself thought, or the consensus of Nietzsche scholars, then they could ask that, and answers would have to explain what those people think rather than their own opinions, and then we might learn something.

Comment: uh. there's a difference between asking "how does anyone work out XYZ" which is not opinion based and asking for an opinion, one which has no answer in the literature

Comment: how can you not see the difference there and use a philosophy site? i'm appalled.

Answer (score -3):

Well, it seems that curiousdannii was right and I confused everyone into thinking I was asking the opinion of their wife / children / pets, rather than a philosopher. Now I've included what I would have assumed was to be taken for granted, on a philosophy site, I expect the helpful and not authoritarian and asinine users of this site to reopen it and cancel their downvotes.

Comment: or not at the case may be hahaha